# South American users or South America users

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I work with IT user support in South America and I'm writing my CV in english.

In my job, I assist users from Brazil, Argentina, Chile and Peru, whats the correct form to put this on my CV :

Support for South America users or Support for South American users ?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider *users **in** South America*, to avoid the possible implication that you specialise in helping people who originally *came* from South America (who now live & work in the US, but sometimes need specialist help from people like you because they're not very fluent in English).

Comment: This might be tricky. I think most users here would go with "South American users", but when I was in the industry a few years back the tendency was going towards "South America...". Possibly an influence of the predominance of Asia people at help centers. FF's comment is also very good.

Comment: "South America users" seems to mean people who use South America.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"South America users" means supporting users who are in South America (who might well want to talk in Swahili).

"South American users" are users from South America (who might well be in Swahili-land).

In a resume I would go with the second one: "All SA users no matter where they are during the call".